# Data too huge to access: Bing Australia Building Footprints

Tags: qgis, geojson, spatialite, large-datasets, australia

I am relatively inexperienced with QGIS. I seeking to access building footprints in a 20km radius from the centre of Melbourne city, Australia.

The dataset I am hoping to use is Bing's 2020 Australia Building Footprint collection that is located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/AustraliaBuildingFootprints) and can be downloaded [here](https://usbuildingdata.blob.core.windows.net/australia-buildings/Australia_2020-06-21.geojson.zip).

The problem I'm encountering is that the unzipped file is a 6+ gb large GeoJSON file, with from what I understand that has no layers, just polygon data. The file covers all of Australia and is too large clearly to large to open straight up in QGIS.

How can I view, filter or trim the data down to access the selection I would like.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Building :) on BERA's answer, you could use `ogr2ogr` to select just buildings within a 20km buffer of Melbourne using a [sqlite sql query](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#sql-sqlite-dialect).

I would still load all buildings to a geopackage first to take advantage of the spatial indexing, then select out Melbourne buildings.

The below SQL statement assumes Melbourne lon, lat is 144.9631,-37.8136, makes a point, reprojects to VicGrid 94 (EPSG:3111), buffers by 20km, projects the buffer back to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and uses that buffer to select any building polys that intersect it.

```
ogr2ogr Australia.gpkg Australia.geojson Australia
ogr2ogr -update -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from Australia a where Intersects(a.geom, Transform(Buffer(Transform(MakePoint(144.9631,-37.8136, 4326), 3111),  20000), 4326))" -nln Melbourne Australia.gpkg Australia.gpkg
```

[image]

Comment: This and the answer below has both helped me to get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Large geojson files can be extremly slow to open and display in QGIS. You can convert it to a geopackage using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) which will open alot quicker.

My environmental variables are broken so I specify full path to the executable but for you it might be enough with just ogr2ogr.

```
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe C:\GIS\GIStest\buildings_sweden.gpkg C:\GIS\GIStest\buildings_sweden.geojson -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=YES
```

[image]

I believe spatial index creation is default, I just added it to be sure.

When you've opened the geopackage in QGIS you can Select the features you want to keep, right-click and export selected features to a new file.

Comment: It is also possible to convert just a subset of data with ogr2ogr. Study the parameters https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html. For example `-spat` can be used for trimming by a bounding box. The conversion is not much faster because GeoJSON is unindexed and ogr2ogr must still read the whole input file.

Comment: This and the other answer has both helped me to get it to work. Thank you!